# Inside a select, just select a row from another table where one column is equal to something

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a select query working fine, but one information is in another table, but this another table is crazy.

[crazy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QasNy.png)

In this table, the info a need is only where the column is equal to CPF

But I can't do this query like usually

My query

```
select
 name,
 date,
 CPF
from user
```

**Yes, there is a primary key between the two tables, codintfunc**

But how I select CPF from the other table if theres 2 condition and inside the select query I can't do this.

PS: sorry my bad english, I'm Brazilian

I've tried select inside a select, joins and where, but no lucky

**More Info**

Because the database has sensitive information, e due to LGPD from Brazil, I made some visual sheet to help understand what I need.

I'm using 3 tables to acquire all data I need in this query

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soA5Z.png)

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh6uU.png)

[table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbT6r.png)

What I need from result is

[wanted_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVGpU.png)

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data from both tables and the result you're trying to get for that sample

Comment: @mureinik, I just updated the question, with more information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on `cod` and add additional conditions to filter only the `typedoc` you need:

```sql
SELECT t1.cod, t1.name, t2.typedoc, t2.numdoc, t3.mat_escocial
FROM   table_1 t1
JOIN   table_2 t2 ON t1.cod = t2.cod AND t2.typedoc = 'cpf'
JOIN   table_3 t2 ON t1.cod = t3.cod
```

Comment: Thank you @mureinik, this works like a glove. I doesn't know that join could do this t2.typedoc = 'cpf'

Comment: One more question, in case that I wanted two typedoc, Do I just add another AND t2.typedoc = 'passport'?

Comment: @MaikoNascimento no - no row in your table can have both `cpf` and `passport`, and you'd get an empty result. Instead, you need another `join` clause with the condition on `passport`, and give it a different alias.